# Convert english date to Chinese culture c#

Tags: c#, date, localization

```
CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo("zh-CN",true);

// normally will have adjusted the application to zh-CN

System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;

System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = culture;


DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
```

Now the result I got is `2023/3/22 ??1:40:39`
but what I want is the **Chinese** characters as well
`2023年3月22日`

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/E2KKgE if you still have `??` instead of `年月日`, please check the font: if it has the required characters or not

Comment: @DmitryBychenko yeah it still has ?? in it. Don't know how to resolved that font issue

Comment: please, check your **font** then: not every font support Chinese; change your font if necessary, try switching to **Lucida Console** (in case of Windows)